# Python for iOS (like RubyMotion)

Tags: python, rubymotion

[RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/) has been released, and I am wondering, if a similar solution is available, or coming for Python?

Comment: [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) claims to support iOS - no idea how good it is.

Comment: Just checked out Kivy and it looks pretty good. iOS is still under development, but it looks like it mostly works.

Comment: Also: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/python-for-ios/id485729872?mt=8

Comment: Re: Python for iOS (previous link), as far as I can see it can't call back to Objective C/Cocoa components?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

RubyMotion isn't a new cross-platform framework (like Kivy, Papaya, Rhodes, etc.) but rather an implementation of the Ruby programming language ON TOP OF the native iOS language Objective-C. Because of this, a RubyMotion object *IS* an Obj-C Object, but you get to use the dynamic Ruby syntax and idioms to deal with it, instead of the static-oriented Objective-C approaches.

You must still learn the Apple SDK, you just talk to it with "toll-free" Ruby code. With Titatnium, for example, you learn that platform's APIs which work on multiple OSes, albeit at a cost of UI mismatches and performance penalties.

MacRuby is the desktop progenitor of RubyMotion, and the Python analogue to it would be PyObjC. The [Sourceforge site](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/) for PyObjC looks dormant to me (last updated in late 2009) so someone would have to first revive it, and then make similar modifications (replacing garbage-collection style memory management with some form of automatic reference counting and binary compilation) in order to build a similar Python solution for iOS.

I wouldn't expect it to drop out of the sky anytime soon, but surprises are always welcome.

Comment: you can't really compare PyObjC and Macruby, PyObjC is a bridge like [RubyCocoa](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rubycocoa/) as you already said MacRuby is Ruby on Top of ObjC runtime. By replacing the Garbage collector from PyObjC will not work since it's a Bridge.

Comment: >>ON TOP OF the native iOS language Objective-C. 

Close, but not quite. It's an implementation of the Ruby Language on top of the Objective-C Runtime binary. Objective-C is an implementation of the Objective-C Language on top of the Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are after and what for. Papaya do what they call a social engine (for games really). But you can write with Python for that. http://papayamobile.com/